# How to use component config permissions on the frontend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, security-token, component-configuration

I am having an issue with the Access component parameters from inside own component. I have tried the code listed in the first answer, but it did not work.

Below is an image of the back end config field, that I would like to access in my front end views.

[image: back end config field I would like to use]

If anyone knows the right way to access this I could use a pointer **:)**

**EDIT UPDATE:**

This is a image of the Database field so it is in the DB
[image: DB image]

And what I entered in my front end file:

```
// Import `ComponentHelper` class.
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;

// Get all params of a specific component.
$params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_sljooma');

// To get the value of the param.
$token_salt = $params->get('security_token');
```

If I `echo $token_salt`, nothing is being returned. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: In your getParams call above you've got com_sljooma instead of com_sljoomla.

Comment: Thank You Robbie can't believe i missed that now its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Import `ComponentHelper` class.
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;

// Get all params of a specific component.
$params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_yourcomponent');

// To get the value of the param.
$params->get('yourParam');
```

Comment: Do i need to build my own Component Helper file to load this info from the Database or is this set up a joomla 3 core?

Comment: It's a core class.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but still could not get it to work so i just created a function in my helper file to pull it from the Database..